# fill spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

i will type my first application on android. I have a problem with fill of data to spinner. I have been used this tutorial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html and a lot of stack but I don't have to correct answer.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.activity_array, R.layout.activity_main_view);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Application has stopped

> View - activity_main_view.xml

Comment: What do you have in activity_main_view ?

Comment: ok it works now! I was changed R.layout.activity_main_view on R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Comment: Nice ! Good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-spinner-dropdown-example.html)

or [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/)

all these are sppiner